# How to store test images as data in a package?

Tags: r, image, package

I'm writing a package that helps to quantify images using R. I would like to store example images that people can use to test the package but I'm not sure how to store them. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can put anything you want into the `inst/` directory of a package.  Let's say you make a directory `inst/images` in your source package, with files `foo1.png`, `foo2.jpg`, and `foo3.tif`. When the package is installed, you can find them via `system.file()`, e.g. list the available files via

```
list.files(system.file("images",package="your_pkg"))
```

or access them via e.g.

```
get_image <- function(fn) {
   system.file("images",fn,package="your_pkg")
}
png::readPNG(get_image("foo1.png"))
```

The only possible pitfall I can think of is that CRAN is not enthusiastic about packages with very large footprints, which could be a problem if (1) you have a lot of large images and (2) you want to submit to CRAN.